# MS SQL: Как сделать несколько триггеров одного типа на одну таблицу

Tags: sql, sql-server, триггер

Субд ms sql. Не дает повесить более одного триггера одинакового типа (например, Instead of insert) на таблицу. Можно ли это исправить? Не хочу пихать кучу проверок в один триггер.

Comment: напиши разрабам письмо =)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

> **В SQL Server существует два параметра, определяющих поведение
> триггеров:**
>
> **AFTER**.
>
> Триггер выполняется после успешного выполнения вызвавших его
> команд. Если же команды по какой-либо причине не могут быть успешно
> завершены, триггер не выполняется. Следует отметить, что изменения
> данных в результате выполнения запроса пользователя и выполнение
> триггера осуществляется в теле одной транзакции: если произойдет откат
> триггера, то будут отклонены и пользовательские изменения. **Можно
> определить несколько AFTER-триггеров для каждой операции (INSERT,
> UPDATE, DELETE)**. Если для таблицы предусмотрено выполнение нескольких
> AFTER-триггеров, то с помощью системной хранимой процедуры
> sp_settriggerorder можно указать, какой из них будет выполняться
> первым, а какой последним. По умолчанию в SQL Server все триггеры
> являются AFTER-триггерами.
>
> **INSTEAD OF**.
>
> Триггер вызывается вместо
> выполнения команд. В отличие от AFTER-триггера INSTEAD OF-триггер
> может быть определен как для таблицы, так и для просмотра. **Для каждой
> операции INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE можно определить только один INSTEAD
> OF-триггер.**

Вот [ссылка](http://datasql.ru/basesql/14.htm) на источник.

Чтоб не загромождать триггер "INSTED OF" я бы раскидал логику по хранимым процедурам и уже их вызывал в самом триггере.